# Define spring property values in Java

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-test

I have some spring beans which wire in property values using the @Value annotation.

e.g.

```
@Value("${my.property}")
private String myField;
```

Usually the values are sourced from property files.

The test I am currently writing uses a fully annotation based configuration.

e.g.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class AcceptanceTest implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "my.package.one",
        "my.package.two"
    })
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public MyBean getMyBean(){
            return new MyBean();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private AnotherBean anotherBean;

    @Test
    public void testTest(){
        assertNotNull(anotherBean);
        . . .
    }   
    . . .
```

I don't wish to reference an external properties file, as I want to keep everything local to the test.

Is there anyway I can specify in java, values for such properties, so that they will be wired in automatically to any beans which need them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Spring Framework 4.1, you can use the `@TestPropertySource` annotation to declare *inlined* properties for the `ApplicationContext` loaded for your tests like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "foo = bar", "magicNumber: 42" })
public class ExampleTests { /* ... */ }
```

Consult the [Context configuration with test property sources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-property-sources) section of the reference manual for details.

---

Prior to Spring Framework 4.1, the easiest way is to configure a custom `PropertySource` and register it with the Spring TestContext Framework (before the `ApplicationContext` is loaded for your test).

You can achieve this by implementing a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer` and using an `org.springframework.mock.env.MockPropertySource` like this:

```java
public class PropertySourceInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
         applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(
           new MockPropertySource().withProperty("foo", "bar"));
    }
}
```

You can then register your initializer for your test like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = PropertySourceInitializer.class)
public class ExampleTests { /* ... */ }
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Does this require `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to work? My tests are in Groovy (using Spock with `SpringApplicationContextLoader`) and reference the configuration class which is in Java. Beans exposed in my config class are being injected but the overridden `initialize` method isn't being called.

Comment: Paul, Spring Boot's `SpringApplicationContextLoader` supports `ApplicationContextInitializer` configuration via `@ContextConfiguration(initializers=...`) (or, AFAIK, via `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(initializers=...)` in later versions of Spock). So in general, it _should_ work. Try the latest version, and if that doesn't work consider opening a bug report against Spock.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one simple approach:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer myConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Map myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        myMap.put("my.property", "my value");
        myMap.put("second.my.property", "another value");
        props.putAll(myMap);

        configurer.setProperties(props);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spock you can also use @TestPropertySource:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = [ "my.test.property = bar", "..." ])
```

It requires the String array to be in Groovy syntax of course, caught me out. I'm using Spock 1.1