# Mock object that has @Value annotation

Tags: junit4, spring-test

I have this class that stores properties for webapp. It is autowired in a service class. I'd like to mock the service and run JUnit Test but it shows that the @Value field could not be autowired.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private myapp.ConfigProperties myapp.SectionServiceImpl.configProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public java.lang.String myapp.ConfigProperties.appFileFolderDocument; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'webapp.root' in string value "${webapp.root}documents\"
```

Source code

```
@Component
public class ConfigProperties {

    @Value("${email.active}")
    public String emailActive;

    @Value("${app.homepage}")
    public String appHomepage;

    @Value("${app.context}")
    public String appContext;

    @Value("${email.username}")
    public String adminEmailAddress;

    @Value("${account.trial.dates}")
    public int trialVersionDates;

    @Value("${app.file.folder.document}")
    public String appFileFolderDocument;

    @Value("${app.file.folder.pdf}")
    public String appFileFolderPdf;

    @Value("${app.file.folder.logo}")
    public String appFileFolderLogo;

    @Value("${app.section.folder.logo}")
    public String appSectionFolderLogo;

    @Value("${app.folder.img}")
    public String appFolderImage;

    @Value("${email.emailAddressMatthijs}")
    public String emailAddressMatthijs;

    @Value("${email.emailAddressInfo}")
    public String emailAddressInfo; 


    // Pagination
    @Value("${pagination.items_per_page}")
    public int paginationItemsPerPage;  

    @Value("${pagination.num_display_entries}")
    public int paginationNumDisplayEntries; 

    @Value("${pagination.num_edge_entries}")
    public int paginationNumEdgeEntries;    


    @Value("${use.pdf.report.newsolution}")
    public int usePdfReportNewSolution; 

    @Value("${use.pdf.report.numberOfIndicatorInPdfReport}")
    public int usePdfReportNumberOfIndicatorInPdfReport;    


    @Value("${recaptcha.publickey}")
    public String captcharPublicKey;    

    @Value("${recaptcha.privatekey}")
    public String captcharPrivateKey;   


    @Value("${file.upload.not.allowed}")
    public String fileUploadNotAllowed;

    @Value("${file.upload.image}")
    public String fileUploadImage;

    @Value("${maxUploadFileSize}")
    public String maxUploadFileSize;

    // Pagination
    @Value("${pagination.admin.items_per_page}")
    public int paginationAdminItemsPerPage; 

    @Value("${pagination.admin.num_display_entries}")
    public int paginationAdminNumDisplayEntries;    

    @Value("${pagination.admin.num_edge_entries}")
    public int paginationAdminNumEdgeEntries;   

}
```

I've tried to create the bean in XML but it still shows the error.

```
<bean id="configProperties" class="myapp.ConfigProperties">
    <property name="appFileFolderDocument" value="E:/myapp/src/main/webapp/documents" />
</bean>
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public java.lang.String myapp.ConfigProperties.appFileFolderDocument; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'webapp.root' in string value "${webapp.root}documents\"
```

configs.properties

```
app.context = http://localhost:8080/myapp/
app.homepage = http://localhost:8080/myapp
app.file.folder.document =  ${webapp.root}documents\\
app.file.folder.pdf = ${webapp.root}pdf\\
app.file.folder.logo = ${webapp.root}companylogo\\
app.section.folder.logo = ${webapp.root}logo\\
app.folder.img = ${webapp.root}images\\
```

JUnit Test file

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:test-context.xml"})
public class IndicatorTemplateDaoTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

test-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:META-INF/properties/config.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="${jdbc.maxactive}"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbc.initialsize}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JpaPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="myapp.dao.impl" >
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="indicatorTemplateDao" class="myapp.dao.impl.IndicatorTemplateDaoImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="indicatorTemplateService" class="myapp.service.impl.IndicatorTemplateServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="indicatorDao" class="myapp.dao.impl.IndicatorDaoImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="indicatorService" class="myapp.service.impl.IndicatorServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="indicatorActionDao" class="myapp.dao.impl.IndicatorActionDaoImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="menuService" class="myapp.service.impl.MenuServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="sectionService" class="myapp.service.impl.SectionServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="configProperties" class="myapp.utils.ConfigProperties">
        <property name="appFileFolderDocument" value="E:/myapp/src/main/webapp/documents" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you set `webapp.root` somewhere?

Comment: Looks like you are not either pointing to correct config XML. Can you sow the annotation where you have configured configuration xml on the TestCase?

Comment: Updated. webapp.root is nowhere.

Comment: For starters, it will never work unless you define `webapp.root` as a property for your test `ApplicationContext`. As for how to do that, answer my next question. ;)

Comment: What version of Spring Framework are you using?

Comment: My Spring version is 3.2.3.RELEASE. In fact, I've already solved the problem by adding "webapp.root" to an extra property file and load it together with `config.properties` using PropertiesLoaderSupport::setLocations() in XML. Thank you @Sam. I still want to know what your solution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, as of Spring Framework 3.1, you should not be using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Instead you should use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` which provides support for a hierarchy of property sources.

As of Spring 3.1, the `<context:property-placeholder ...>` XML namespace element automatically uses the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` behind the scenes.

So once you've switched to `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, you can simply follow my instructions in this related discussion:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23827645/388980

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)